# Create Object with Values from Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object that contains a listing of unique column names:

```
["heading", "startDate", "finishDate"]
```

I am returning an XML data set that looks like similar to this this:

```
<z:row ows_heading='Header' ows_startDate='1/1/2016' ows_finishDate='1/11/2016' ows_Description='Ignore me'/>
<z:row ows_heading='Header' ows_startDate='2/3/2016' ows_finishDate='2/12/2016' ows_Description='Ignore me'/>
```

How do I loop through the unique column name object to get the column name, append "ows_" to it and then find the resulting value and add it back to the object so that the end result is something like:

```
["heading": "Header", "startDate": "1/1/2016", "finishDate": "1/11/2016"]
```

EDIT: Current code block:

```
var a=[];var obj={};
        $(r).find("[nodeName=z:row]").each(function() 
        {
            $.each(uniqHeaderVals, function( key, value ) {
                var thisVal = $(this).attr("ows_"+value);
                obj.value = thisVal;
            });

            a.push(obj);
        });
        console.log(a);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Are you asking how to loop through an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @ScottMarcus almost correct answer

```js
var arry = ["heading", "startDate", "finishDate"];

var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("z:row");

var resultArry = [].map.call(elems, function(elem) {
  // For each element, create an object
  return arry.reduce(function(result, attr) {
    result[attr] = elem.getAttribute('ows_' + attr);
    return result;
  }, {});
});
console.log(resultArry);
```

```html
<z:row ows_heading='Header' ows_startDate='1/1/2016' ows_finishDate='1/11/2016' ows_Description='Ignore me'/>
<z:row ows_startDate='2/3/2016' ows_finishDate='2/12/2016' ows_Description='Ignore me' ows_heading='Header' />
```

The difference with this code is that it uses the attribute name, rather than position

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the elements and for each one loop through its attributes and extract the attribute values?

Your result will need to be an array of objects though:

```
[ 
   { "heading": "Header", "startDate": "1/1/2016", "finishDate": "1/11/2016" },
   { "heading": "Header", "startDate": "2/3/2016", "finishDate": "2/12/2016" }
]
```

Since this: `["heading": "Header", "startDate": "1/1/2016", "finishDate": "1/11/2016"]` is not a valid structure.

```js
var arry = ["heading", "startDate", "finishDate"];

var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("z:row");

var resultArry = [];

// Loop through the XML elements
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i){
  
  // For each element, create an object
  var obj = {};
  
  // Loop through the element's attributes
  for(var x = 0; x < elems[i].attributes.length - 1; ++x){
    // For each attribute, create a property value
    obj[arry[x]] = elems[i].attributes[x].value;
  }
  resultArry.push(obj);
}

console.log(resultArry);
```

```html
<z:row ows_heading='Header' ows_startDate='1/1/2016' ows_finishDate='1/11/2016' ows_Description='Ignore me'/>
<z:row ows_heading='Header' ows_startDate='2/3/2016' ows_finishDate='2/12/2016' ows_Description='Ignore me'/>
```

Comment: your code is flawed if the order of the attributes in a `z:row` is different to the order in `arry`

Comment: True, but since the OP told us what the XML schema is, my code is not flawed.

Comment: the schema doesn't dictate the order of attributes

Comment: I understand, but you miss the point. I am taking the OP at his word and providing a solution based on that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have the xml string in a variable. In that case, you could do it like this:

```js
var uniqHeaderVals = ["heading", "startDate", "finishDate"]

var xml = "<z:row ows_heading='Header' ows_startDate='1/1/2016' ows_finishDate='1/11/2016' ows_Description='Ignore me'/>"
    + "<z:row ows_heading='Header' ows_startDate='2/3/2016' ows_finishDate='2/12/2016' ows_Description='Ignore me'/>";

var r = $('<content>' + xml + '</content>'); // valid XML needs a single root

var a = r.find('z\\:row').get().map(function (node) {
    return uniqHeaderVals.reduce( function (o, title) {
        var attr = $(node).attr('ows_' + title);
        if (attr) o[title] = attr;
        return o;
    }, {})
});

console.log(a);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const XML_INPUT = `
<z:row ows_heading='Header' ows_startDate='1/1/2016' ows_finishDate='1/11/2016' ows_Description='Ignore me'/>
<z:row ows_heading='Header' ows_startDate='2/3/2016' ows_finishDate='2/12/2016' ows_Description='Ignore me'/>`;
const COLUMNS = ['heading', 'startDate', 'finishDate'];

console.log(children(toDom(XML_INPUT)).reduce(toRow, []));

function toDom(str) {
    var tmp = document.createElement('div');
    tmp.innerHTML = str;
    return tmp;
}

function children(nodes) {
  return [...nodes.querySelectorAll('*')];
}

function toRow(p, node) {    
    p.push(COLUMNS.reduce((p, c) => {
        p[c] = attr(node, c);
        return p;
    }, {}));
    return p;
}

function attr(node, name) {
    return node.getAttribute('ows_' + name);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```